# ¿Cómo Calcular el tiempo de carga de un sitio web en el navegador?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

quisiera saber como obtener el tiempo que tarda en cargar un sitio web, es decir el tiempo del frontend y el tiempo del backend.

para el backend que esta en php uso lo siguiente:

```
<?php
  $tiempo_inicial = microtime(true);

  $htmlpage="<html><head></head><body></body></html>";
  echo $htmlpage;
  $tiempo_final = microtime(true);
  $tiempo = $tiempo_final - $tiempo_inicial;
  echo "se cargo el sitio web en ".$tiempo;
?>
```

pero no se si se esta mostrando en segundos o hay que hacer una conversión previa, aqui la variable tiempo es el tiempo que transcurre hasta que se ejecuta todo el script que seria el tiempo de carga del backend.

para el frontend que se tendria que usar javascript queria saber cual seria el equivalente, es decir el tiempo hasta que la pagina esta lista para usarse por el usuario, ese seria el tiempo de frontend que tendria que sumarse con el del backend para tener el tiempo completo.

Comment: El tiempo con `microtime()` se mide en microsegundos, la documentación de PHP indica: "microtime — Devuelve la fecha Unix actual con microsegundos"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es necesario jugar con la hora actual, todos los valores ya están en [window.performance.timing](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Navigation_timing_API).

- Valor en milisegundos desde el inicio hasta *DOM Content Loaded*:

  ```
  window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd - window.performance.timing.navigationStart
  ```
- Valor en milisegundos desde el inicio hasta *DOM Complete*:

  ```
  window.performance.timing.domComplete - window.performance.timing.navigationStart
  ```
- Solamente los milisegundos que tardó en renderizar la página:

  ```
  window.performance.timing.domComplete - window.performance.timing.domLoading
  ```
- Valor en milisegundos desde el inicio hasta *Load End*:

  ```
  window.performance.timing.loadEventEnd - window.performance.timing.navigationStart
  ```